# How to sort DataTable Rows without creating DataView?

Tags: c#

How to sort DataTable rows and get it as DataTable on output? I've started this way:

```
var sortExpression="city ASC";
var rows = dt.Select("", sortExpression);
```

But I don't know how to create another table with this rows and columns from original dt DataTable.

Comment: You can use LINQ DataTableExtensions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var newTable = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
  DataTable dt;

  dt.DefaultView.Sort=sortExpression;
```