# DataTable Sorting without creating new DataTable with maintaining RowState

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using `DataTable`. In which I want to sort on particular columns without creating copy. I have also tried with `DataTable.Select()` but it required new table for sorted output which will be not worked for me as my source datatable is bound with control.

You can take any example of `DataTable`

So how can I achieve the task?

Comment: This has a ans here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527251/how-to-sort-datatable-rows-without-creating-dataview

Comment: I already gone through this link. In suggested link, it will create a copy of `DataTable` to obtain sorted output. In my case, i want apply sort on same `DataTable`. Please do let me know for more information.

Comment: dt.DefaultView.Sort=sortExpression;

Comment: In this case, I cannot see the sorted output in table "dt". So result will not be reflected in binding control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you to achieve your requirement

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> data = from dt in dtTemp.AsEnumerable()
orderby dt.Field<Int32>("IDColumn"), dt.Field<String>("NameColumn") ascending
select dt;
```

Comment: Will it sort `dtTemp`? sorted data will be available in `data` right? Then how it answers the question?

Comment: Sorting will not be applied on dtTemp `DataTable` but using above code I can get the rows collection in sorted order so using that collection I will import rows in binded `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code as an example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Populate dt here

dt.DefaultView.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", "column name here", "ASC"); //sort ascending

dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: dt.DefaultView.ToTable(); will create new datatable with sorted output which is not required in my case.